# How to restore blackboard symbols in Emacs

Tags: fonts, emacs

I am using Emacs in Agda mode. Today, it stopped rendering most of the blackboardable symbols (`\b0`, `\b1`, `\bM`, ...), though still does everything else (`\bN`, `\bZ`, `\bR`, `\r`, `\Pi`, `\Sigma`, ...).

The symbols that dont render appear as squares filled with their unicode sequence as shown below.

[image]

I'm using GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2021-03-26 on Windows 11

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was just a simple font issue. Not sure how it changed, but downloaded JuliaMono and set that as the default font. All working now.